# Store a long html text in firebase

Tags: firebase

I am using firebase with ionic.
I have my filed text where i would like to put an html text, everything was ok until i had to add a very long text as http://www.gutenberg.org/files/45334/45334-h/45334-h.htm

Is there a limit to save a long text in firebase?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Firebase's documentation on limitations and restrictions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-limitations):

- Size of one child value - 10mb (UTF-8 encoded)

So most likely your book is bigger than that.